# Swift MapKit - My map crashes when I zoom in on the clusters

Tags: swift, mapkit, mkannotationview, mapkitannotation

This is the error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x18525ed8c 0x1844185ec 0x1851f7750 0x18512aa18 0x19621fbcc 0x1960b0e40 0x196128ee8 0x18512d3a0 0x196129ab8 0x1961f8e54 0x196075eac 0x185cab3d4 0x185207aa8 0x18520776c 0x185207010 0x185204b60 0x185124da8 0x187109020 0x18f141758 0x10430352c 0x184bb5fc0)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

**I follow this example:**

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/237/

This example also crashed when you put 100 markers

Help please

Comment: Please add your code.

Answer (score 1):

I already found the error.
This is my erroneous code:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    guard let annotation = annotation as? Cycle else { return nil }

    switch annotation.type {
    case .unicycle:
        return UnicycleAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: UnicycleAnnotationView.ReuseID)
    case .bicycle:
        return BicycleAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: BicycleAnnotationView.ReuseID)
    case .tricycle:
        return TricycleAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: TricycleAnnotationView.ReuseID)
    }
```

////
guard let annotation = annotation as? Cycle else { return nil }

It can not be null at any time

This is good code:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    guard let annotation = annotation as? Cycle else { return ClusterAnnotationView() }

    switch annotation.type {
    case .unicycle:
        return UnicycleAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: UnicycleAnnotationView.ReuseID)
    case .bicycle:
        return BicycleAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: BicycleAnnotationView.ReuseID)
    case .tricycle:
        return TricycleAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: TricycleAnnotationView.ReuseID)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a check before you add objects into your array. But do post some code so we can give more feedback. But just judging from what you posted it points to inserting something that is nil into an array.